# How to use a logical operator as variable in a where clause in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```sql
declare @operator as varchar (10) = '>='

select Saldo from account where Saldo @operator 0
```

Comment: You can't, that isn't how SQL works; you can't just dumb a variable in a location and expect the data engine to interpret it as an operator, object name, value, based on your intent. This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), if I am honest.

Comment: SQL Server (and all databases) don't execute SQL directly. They compile it into an execution plan based on the query, the table schema, indexes and data statistics. It's the execution plan that gets executed and produces the results. You can't pass an operator as a parameter any more than you can pass `==` as a parameter in C#.

Comment: `any turn arounds` for what problem? Why did you try to pass the operator as a parameter in the first place? Are you trying to create a catch-all stored procedure? That's almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Imagine if you had some (odd) set up like this: `SELECT [LIKE] FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE [LIKE] LIKE 'LIKE';` Now, let's do `DECLARE @Variable varchar(10) = 'LIKE'; SELECT [LIKE] FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE [LIKE] LIKE @Variable;` What should `@Variable` be interpreted as? The *column* `LIKE`? The operator `LIKE`? The `varchar` `'LIKE'`? *Something else*?

Comment: An equality check requires a completely different execution plan from a range check or comparison. With an equality check, the database can use an index to find the values that match it exactly, then identify the rows included in that index entry and return them. With a comparison or range check the server will have to find the start (or end) index entry of the range and return the rows included in every index entry. If the estimated number of rows is too big, the server may decide to not use the index at all

Comment: i could see that is question was an XY, but i ended up dois some other way

Answer (score -2):

You could use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) something like this:

DECLARE @operator AS NVARCHAR (10) = '>='

DECLARE @SQLCmd AS NVARCHAR(64) = 'SELECT Saldo FROM  ACCOUNT WHERE Saldo ' + @operator + ' 0'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLCmd

Comment: am using a store procedure and even though your answer did not help but it gave me some insight. Thank you

Comment: That was the idea,  not to solve your specific problem but to help you figured it out.